# Cannot be resolved or is not a field (Notepad exercises from android dev website)

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, notepad

I'm running through the notepad exercises on the android dev website, currently working on exercise (found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex2.html)).

I came to the end of the tutorial and found that I had several errors in the main two java files regarding R file relations, such as `setContentView(R.layout.notes_list);` and `menu.add(0, INSERT_ID,0, R.string.menu_insert);`

I've tried cleaning and re-genning `R.java` to no avail.

These also occur in the solution for the exercise so I think they are deliberate mistakes, or something with my eclipse, but I can't seem to fix them, any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Do you have the layout notes_list.xml in your layout folder?
Do you have a string by the name of menu_insert in your strings.xml?
This might be the issue, because I think they don't give EVERYTHING in the tutorial...
They do have them in the solution :

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/no_notes"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

in strings.xml in values folder :

```
<string name="menu_insert">Add Note</string>
```

Comment: The short answer is yes to all the above

Comment: Then, try to check the imports at the top of your class, sometimes this dumb Eclipse imports the R class from the android package and stops using yours.

Comment: Haha great thats sorted it, guess I should have spotted that! I thought it was importing mine but thanks, that has fixed it.
Im not a huge fan of Eclipse. Do you know how well the netbeans plugin for android performs?

Comment: No idea, I've only been using Eclipse. Always worked properly for me. And if not,  there is plentiful of doc and forum to find answers

Answer (score 5):

I think you might have to be careful about how you use the ctrl-shift-O command (to auto-insert the "import" statements at the top of the file). It could be that you get the "import android.R;" statement as a "bonus". I commented-out the "import android.R;" statement, and everything was fine.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, main problem is that Eclipse importing android.R, when ctrl+shift+o pressed. Another way to fix problem is declaring import with full path:

```
import com.android.demo.notepad2.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see that you've added an id to your LinearLayout in whatever layout xml file you're using.  If that's the case, then you should look for something syntactically wrong that would prevent the R file from being rebuilt.

Something like:

```
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
```

Answer (score 0):

While hardcoding string, don't use space in both `.xml` files. i.e `@string/a b c` is wrong try `@string/a_b_c`